# how to preserve zeros on the left of digits as numbers in JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I declared the var **numero** to represent digits under 10 as numbers, but I struggled saving zeros on the left of these numbers!

```
let start = 10, end = 0, stopYo = 3;

for (let i = start; i >= stopYo; i--) {
  let numero = `0${i}`;
  if (i == start)console.log(i);
  else if (i < start) console.log(+numero);
}
```

I tried using unary method, but it removed the zero on the left.
How can I keep zeros on the left of digits without turning them into strings?

Comment: Numbers are just numbers, they don't have any "leading zeros". Does `I've got 0003 apples` make any sense to you?

Comment: Leading zeros are for _presentation only_. Presentation is for _strings only_. Use [`padStart`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart).

Comment: My teacher made his output code as 09 08 and so on. So, I asked if there's a way doing it

Comment: No, there is no way doing this as numbers. You have to use strings (or four seperate number `0`, `9`, `0`, `8`)